# Windows 10 safely delete recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, partition, data-recovery, diskpart

One of our processing PCs uses Windows 10 Pro, and I am the one in the unfortunate position of trying to upgrade the capacity of its C:\ drive (SSD) from 1TB to 2TB.

I created an image backup using the "Windows 7" backup tool, removed the old SSD, plugged in the new one, and restored the image backup onto it. Booted it up, working same as before, as expected. Only difference is 860GB of unallocated space at the end of the disk, as expected.

The big problem here, is the Windows Recovery Partition. This little bugger places itself at the ***end*** of the disk, sandwiching the C:\ drive for reasons I cannot fathom. Windows doesn't let you move it, or delete it, or in any way touch it, through its UI tools. So basically, Windows is blocking me from expanding the C:\ drive to use the extra space, which is the entire reason for this upgrade.

Googling the issue has given me two options:

- A plethora of very aggressively marketed freemium partitioning software of questionable trustworthiness, hyper-optimized to place themselves in every search result of any query relating to Windows disk management.
- Using `diskpart` CLI to forcibly delete the partition.

Seeing as all of these tools would require admin privileges to do what they claim to do, and I don't believe I have permission to install third party software to accomplish this (especially that which requires admin privileges), that leaves me with the following `diskpart` steps, which almost every answer suggested in some form:

1. `diskpart` to start the tool
2. `list disks`
3. `select disk 1` to select the SSD
4. `list partitions`
5. `select partition 4` to select the recovery partition (980MB, last in the disk, labeled "Recovery")
6. `delete partition override` to remove the partition forcibly

To their credit, this *did* remove the partition. Opening Disk Management UI showed the partition as removed. I expanded C:\ to fill the remaining space, and rebooted. PC shuts down, goes through UEFI, starts to boot into Windows, but then no fan noises. Monitor is on but displaying black. No response to anything, including short press of power button. Five minutes of idling later, I force shut it down with long press.

Second attempt, it seemed to boot into Windows normally. I log in and it displays the "Welcome" loading screen. This continues for 20 minutes. No response to short press of power button. I force shut it down.

So now I'm currently re-imaging it again with the backup. This takes several hours. I would rather not be forced to re-image it a third time. Every answer stated that the Recovery Partition is safe to delete, but that appears to not be true here. My only guess is that there's some extra step needed for this machine that isn't applicable to most. **What is the *safe and stable* procedure to remove or move the recovery partition such that I can expand the C:\ partition to make use of the rest of the disk?**

Previous answers that did not work:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1622060/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-recovery-partition
- https://superuser.com/questions/1023765/how-to-delete-the-recovery-partition-in-windows-10
- https://superuser.com/questions/1073883/cant-remove-recovery-partition

What is not an answer:

- Installing third-party tools that I don't have permission to install and don't trust with admin privileges on a machine with sensitive data.
- Allocating the space on the other side of the partition as D:\ and telling my boss he needs to split the processing storage across two drives, just because Windows does a dumb thing.
- Reinstalling Windows and all of the necessary programs and configs all over again.
- Pointing me to the same exact steps with `diskpart` I listed above.

Comment: I really can't think of such a scenario. Regardless, there are plenty of partition management tools, some free, that will do this. Off topic, and not a usual or customary procedure.

Comment: Could you explain why you think this is off-topic? The first item in [on-topic help](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) is "managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks", which this is, and this is a machine in a business environment, not a consumer environment.

If ServerFault only accepts questions about publicly-facing servers, and does not accept questions about business workstations, then perhaps that should be added to the help page?

Comment: This isn't something that can be fixed natively. There are tools/products to do this, but it's off topic to recommend those here.

Comment: Are you certain of this? My suspicion is that there may be an unknown *something* is expecting to find the partition where it isn't, possibly filesystem-level or maybe even in the registry somewhere, that I'm missing that needs to be set for this machine. From the phrasing it sounds like you don't know any more about what went wrong than I do, but if you know what it is and are sure it cannot be changed without third-party tools, please help me understand.

Comment: I've done this many times with no ill effects. The recovery partition isn't required for Windows to boot up or operate. I suspect your problem is actually with the new SSD itself or with the method you used to backup and restore it. I'd suggest installing Windows 10 fresh on the SSD and see if it operates normally before going to the trouble of restoring it again from the backup.

Comment: @GregAskew It's not so complicated since the recovery partition is at the end of the disk now (it wasn't always like this), so you can do this with all Windows tools.

Answer (score 1):

***This answer is intended for Windows version 2004*** *and newer, where the recovery partition (if exists) is [after system partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBrFd.png). In 1909 and older the [partition may be located before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yje0.png) the system partition, requiring a more complicated solution.*

---

```
reagentc /disable

diskpart
list disk 
select dis [diskNumber]
list partition
sel part [partitionNumber]
del par override
```

Then expand the disk all the way if you don't want to recreate the recovery partition.

You can shrink it if you decide to recreate the partition later (use **[DISM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yje0.png)** to [mount a WinRE WIM from a source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-tool-to-the-windows-re-boot-options-menu?view=windows-11) ISO, then copy [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-11) to the recovery partition that you create, for example).

Windows might already move the recovery partition to a hidden directory at `C:\Recovery` when you do `reagentc /disable`. You should read more about the topics to make sure.

**Update on REAgentC:**
I recently had to extend a sandwiched partition by deleting the recovery partition, and bookmarking the process with `REAgentC /enable` and `/disable` worked without any extra steps:
[image: After deleting the recovery partition and extending the Windows partition, I add a primary partition for WinRE and simply run reagentc /enable]

---

Further reading:

- [Partition samples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oem-deployment-of-windows-desktop-editions-sample-scripts?preserve-view=true&view=windows-10#-createpartitions-uefitxt)
- [REAgentC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/reagentc-command-line-options?view=windows-11)